# Setting maxLenght of edittext

Tags: xamarin.android

How to set the maximum number of characters allowed to be written.

```
 textc.TextChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (textc.Text.Length >16)
                {
                    return;
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the max lenght of [EditText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.widget.edittext?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9) by:

```
EditText editText = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.EDT);
editText.SetFilters(new IInputFilter[] { new InputFilterLengthFilter(10) });
```